# Why is my sub class method overriding my super class' method when calling super().mymethod()?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a sub class of a class where some of the super class' methods are given some default values during instantiation. Below is some code that replicates the problem that I'm having, while ignoring the details of my implantation. It appears that my sub classes method signatures are overriding the super class' method signatures (see error below).

I don't understand why the super class is calling the sub class' implementation of `add`. I think I'm missing a fundamental concept here, what might that be?

Additionally, what is the proper way to handle a situation like this?

```py
class Base:
    def __init__(self, factor):
        self.factor = factor

    def add(self, a, b):
        return a + b

    def add_and_multiply(self, a, b):
        return self.add(a, b) * self.factor
        
class DefaultClass(Base):
    def __init__(self, factor, a):
        self.a = a

    def add(self, b):
        return super().add(self.a, b)

    def add_and_multiply(self, b):
        return super().add_and_multiply(self.a, b)

b = Base(5)
d = DefaultClass(5, 1)
print(b.add_and_multiply(1, 1))
print(d.add_and_multiply(1))
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [27], line 24
     22 d = DefaultClass(5, 1)
     23 print(b.add_and_multiply(1, 1))
---> 24 print(d.add_and_multiply(1))

Cell In [27], line 19, in DefaultClass.add_and_multiply(self, b)
     18 def add_and_multiply(self, b):
---> 19     return super().add_and_multiply(self.a, b)

Cell In [27], line 9, in Base.add_and_multiply(self, a, b)
      8 def add_and_multiply(self, a, b):
----> 9     return self.add(a, b) * self.factor

TypeError: add() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: That's what's _supposed_ to happen. `self.add` during the call to `d.add_and_multiply` is `DefaultClass`'s implementation, which doesn't accept two arguments. You're breaking the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks, for pointing that out. I guess I should read up on SOLID principles. Do you know of a pattern for implementing a class that has defaults for a super class? Or is this just a bad idea?